# Get outer indecies of a region in a logical image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, region, indices

If I've any `m x n` logical image of a white region like the following:

[image: Logical image of a region]

How to get the indices of the boundary line between the white and black regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply comes down to detecting the edges of the given image. MATLAB already has a built-in implementation for that in the [`edge`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) command. Here's an example of detecting the boundaries of an image `I` using the Canny filter:

```
A = edge(I, 'canny');
```

The non-zero elements in the resulting image `A` are what you're after. You can then use `find` to obtain their indices.

Comment: if just used `[i j] = find(A);` after your code, thanks a lot :).

Comment: @EitanT - is there a special reason why you use `edge` instead of morphological operations in this case?

Comment: @Shai because it gives the desired result in one line... (I didn't think that speed was an issue here).

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is a clear binary image, there is no need to use `edge` as suggested by @EitanT.

Getting the perimeter using morphological operations [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html), [`imerode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) and [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

```
% let input image be bw
we = bw & ~imerode( bw, strel('disk', 1) ); % get a binary image with only the boundary pixels set
st = regionprops(we, 'PixelIdxList'); % get the linear indices of the boundary

% get a binary image with pixels on the outer side of the shape set
be = ~bw & imdilate( bw, strel('disk', 1) );
st = regionprops(be, 'PixelList'); % get the row-col indices of the boundary
```

Comment: better than using edge detection..:)